# CSS dropdown menu - How to put before element in foreground of select/option element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set a CSS `:before` the element in the foreground?
basically, I need to make the text get behind the grey area where the dropdown arrow is located.

I already tried to give the before element z-index: 2 and the actual element z-index: 1
but with no noticeable effect so far.
The text will always flow over the select arrow of the dropdown menu, which to me looks ugly.

My Idea now was to simply set the before element on top of the select/option element of the dropdown menu to make the text flow behind the grey area.
But it seems that the z-index gets ignored onto these pseudo-elements for some reason...

Can somebody give me a hint on that?

[image]

HTML:

```xml
<div role="button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown category-dropdown">
    <span>{{ category_objects.category }}</span>
</div>
```

Raw browser output:

```xml
<div role="button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown category-dropdown">
    <span><select name="category" id="id_category">
        <option value="d6f13bec-f855-453b-ad2f-a426a42bde06">Hello World 1232i</option>
    </select></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.category-dropdown {
    z-index: 1;
}

.category-dropdown select {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 31.5px;
    color: #424242;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 10vw;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 125px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-indent: 3px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.category-dropdown::before,
.category-dropdown::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.category-dropdown::after { /*  Custom dropdown arrow */
    content: "\25BC";
    font-size: .625em;
    line-height: 1;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    margin-top: -.5em;
}

.category-dropdown select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-overflow: '';
}

.category-dropdown::before {
    width: 1.5em;
    right: 9px;
    top: 6px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

.category-dropdown select[disabled] {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.category-dropdown select[disabled]::after {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.category-dropdown::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.category-dropdown::after {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
```

All other CSS-related stuff comes from bootstrap.

Comment: @RachelGallen Relevant html has been added.

Comment: can you insert the ouputted source code (or at least a sample) in the span

Comment: @RachelGallen Has also been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.
But the text seems to look above the arrow because the background (before) is given an opacity.

Can you please check if this helps. I have just replaced the background color for before with another color

```css
.category-dropdown {
    z-index: 1;
}

.category-dropdown select {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 31.5px;
    padding-right: 1.6em;
    color: #424242;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 10vw;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 125px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-indent: 3px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.category-dropdown::before,
.category-dropdown::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.category-dropdown::after { /*  Custom dropdown arrow */
    content: "\25BC";
    font-size: .625em;
    line-height: 1;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    margin-top: -.5em;
}

.category-dropdown select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-overflow: '';
}

.category-dropdown::before {
    width: 1.5em;
    right: 9px;
    top: 6px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

.category-dropdown select[disabled] {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.category-dropdown select[disabled]::after {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.category-dropdown::before {
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
}

.category-dropdown::after {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div role="button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown category-dropdown">
     <span><select name="category" id="id_category">
         <option value="d6f13bec-f855-453b-ad2f-a426a42bde06">Hello World 1232i</option>
     </select></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, works like a charm, thanks for your time and helping me out onto this!